# Does pseudospin break the crystal symmetry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-spin, symmetry-breaking, crystals

Pseudospin is a concept to describe a superposition of two quantum states.
Sometimes, I see a pseudospin texture in the momentum space which breaks a crystal symmetry.

A simple example is the graphene, where the pseudospin represents the A and B sublattices.
The pseudospin at +k is opposite to the one at -k.
However, the graphene possesses the inversion symmetry which enforces,
in case of the real spin, the spin states at +k and -k to be the same.

How can pseudospin break the inversion symmetry?
What am I confusing?

Edit:
The real spin exists in the real space, while the pseudospin exists in a different space, namely, the sublattice space.
We are dealing with the direct product of these spaces.
So, the inversion operation in the real space operates differently in the sublattice space.
Is that right?